# How can I bend a slanted PVC pipe to vertical?

Tags: drain, pvc, kitchen-island

We're using an AAV for our island drain, but before I can attach it the pipe coming out of the slab is not vertical. How do I fix that?

Additional Information:

I haven't attempted to measure how far out of plumb it is, but I don't believe it's enough that even the smallest standard fitting will do the trick. I've considered either heat and bend or cut and install a flex coupling. The AAVs I've read about are looking for a five degree tolerance if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Pictures would clarify this question. Please [edit] to add at least one.

Comment: Just how crooked is it?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

Standard drain pipe elbows (or "bends") are available in (at least) 15, 22.5, 30, 45, 60 and 90 degree bends. You may not find all those at a "box store" but online or at a plumbing supply they can be had. 11.25 degrees is also made, I find.

With due care & caution, you can also heat PVC plumbing and bend it - but due care is required so as not to kink it, overheat it, or otherwise cause damage. Fittings are harder to screw up, and can likely get you close enough to vertical that it won't matter.

As to your assertion that "even the smallest standard fitting would not do it" that would be *unlikely:*

- If it's less than 5 degrees, it's within tolerance.
- If it's more than 5 degrees, and less than 6.25 degrees, you'd be
  right, though there's enough slop in the fit up that you could be
  wrong by applying pressure correctly when gluing.
- If it's more than 6.25 degrees, then an 11.25 degree bend will get
  you within tolerance.

So you have 1.25 degrees where that *could* be true. If it's more than 13 degrees, you use a 15 degree bend, etc...

Or there's @Isherwood's solution if you want
*perfect*, rather than within tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

***Two* elbows.**

Install two low-angle elbows and adjust them as needed. The combination will allow for any angle. You can even implement an offset to adjust position if needed.